# A problem with non-linear polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose that $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in the complex numbers such that $f(x,y)=0$ defines a non-linear variety of dimension 1.

How could I show that there is no $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\alpha\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is not identically equal to zero?

---

My attempt:

Suppose otherwise. If $\alpha=0$ then from the equation we would have $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$, and so $f(x,y)=g(y)$ for some polynomial $g(y)\in \mathbb{C}[y]$, but in this case the equation $f(x,y)=g(y)=0$ defines a finite union of varieties given by equations of the form $y=z_i$ for some $z_1,\ldots,z_m\in\mathbb{C}$.

Now, we can write the polynomial in the form $\displaystyle{f=\sum_{k=0}^n g_k(y)\cdot x^k}$ where $g_k(y)\in \mathbb{C}[y]$. Making the calculations we have that

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\alpha\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\alpha\cdot g_n'(y)\cdot x^n+\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left((k+1)\cdot g_{k+1}(y)+\alpha\cdot g'_k(y) \right)\cdot x^k\right)
\end{align*}
and if it is equal to the zero polynomial then we would have:

$$\begin{cases}g'_n(y)=0\\ (k+1)\cdot g_{k+1}(y)+\alpha\cdot g'_k(y)=0\end{cases}$$

This implies that the polynomials $g_k(y)$ have degree $n-k$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n$ (as one can find them recursively), but this does not take me to a contradiction.

On the other hand, if we make the calculations with the polynomial $f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$, it turns out that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\alpha\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\equiv 0$ if and only if $b^2=4ac$, in which case we would have that $f(x,y)=\left(ax+\dfrac{b}{2a}\right)^2$.

The latter make me think that perhaps one has to use irreducibility of the non-linear variety, but I still do not know how to argue.

Comment: Yes, you need to assume irreduciblity (at least no repeated factors) for $f$ to achieve what you want. Then, the condition you have will show that $g=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}+\alpha\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$ will divide $f$, but $\deg g<\deg f$ and irreducibility should lead where you want to go.

Comment: If $\alpha\not =0$ and  $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\alpha \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$, I think that you can put $g(x,y)=f(x+y, \alpha y)$. You have $\displaystyle \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=0$.

Comment: @Mohan The condition that I have is that $g=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\alpha \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is identically 0. How does this imply that $g$ divide $f$?

Comment: @Kelenner,  I do not understand what would be the contradiction if $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}=0$ with $g(x,y)=f(x+y,\alpha y)$.

Comment: You can not have $g=0$ identically, try writing $f$ as a sum of homogeneous polynomials of various degrees and see why not. You do not need this, but just $g=0$ at all points where $f=0$.

Comment: If $ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=0$, this means that $f(x+y,\alpha y)=h(x)$ where $h$ is a polynomial. This is almost what you have done in the beginning.

Comment: @Mohan The point of the question is exactly to show that $g$ cannot be identically zero, that is precisely what I do not understand. I tried your suggestion of writing $f$ as sum of homogeneous polynomials, but could not finish!

Comment: @Kelenner I agree that is similar to what I did, but the difference before was that $f(x,y)=h(x)$ implies that the variable $y$ is not used in the polynomial. In the case where $f(x+y,\alpha y)=h(x)$, it does not have the same effect: If you put $f(x,y)=(x+y)^2$ then $f(x+y,\alpha\cdot x)=x^2$ (for $\alpha=-1$). In this case the problem is irreducibility, but it is still possible that $f(x+y,y)=h(x)$.

Comment: @Wore Sorry I was not here for some time. Perhaps I do not understand the problem, but to solve $f(u,v)=0$, put $y=v/\alpha$, $x=u-v/\alpha$. Then as $f(x+y,\alpha y)=h(x)$, you have  $h(x)=0$, so if $x_k$ are the roots of $h$, we get that $f(u,v)=0$ is equivalent to exists $k$, $u-v/\alpha=x_k$, a contradiction with the hypothesis.

Comment: @Kelenner Now I got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Wore You are welcome!